# LibreOffice fails to export PDF containing arabic letters

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, openoffice, arabic

I used LibreOffice to write an arabic document.

When exporting this document to PDF through the LibreOffice "File -> Export...", I get an unexpected result:  the PDF is different from the original document (it has modified characters and letters which destroys the meaning).

I suspect it to be linked with right to left writting languages as I have no problem with English or French export but face the same problem with Farsi.
I installed the arabic language pack for LibreOffice but it didn't help.

Do you know what could be done to solve this issue?

Thanks!

EDIT : I use LibreOffice Version: 6.0.7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

EDIT 2 : When copying the arabic content of a PDF I have a similar pattern everytime I paste it (to LibreOffice, firefox, gedit...).
For the sentence :

ما زلت أحاول  نسخ محتويات مستند مكتوب باللغة العربية.

I get the copy/paste from PDF :

ما زلت أحاول نسخ محتويات مستند مكتوب باللغة العربية أحاول نسخ محتويات مستند مكتوب باللغة العربية نسخ محتويات مستند مكتوب باللغة العربية محتويات مستند مكتوب باللغة العربيةت مستند مكتوب باللغة العربية مكتوب باللغة العربية باللغة العربية.

So the result  starts with the whole sentence, then goes from the word 2 till the end, then from word 3 till the end, then word 4 till the end, then word 5 till the end and finally word 6 till the end... So the result contains 6 times the last 4 words. Same pattern happens every time.
I think it is due to LibreOffice export, cause the formatting looks good on Adobe, but if I open the exported PDF with LibreOffice Draw, it is destroyed.

Comment: It helps to know what version of LibreOffice you are running and, in this case, what your operating system is (relates to fonts and character encoding). Please edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

While it will not fix the issue with LibreOffice, have you considered using a "print to pdf" utility? Basically it shows up as a printer on your computer but when you print to it you can save the print output as a PDF file. If printing of Arabic and Farsi is working then this should work as well.

On Windows there is such a tool that comes with the free Foxit Reader. Adobe also provides such a tool with their Adobe Acrobat PDF editor (not Acrobat Reader).

Comment: There is the same problem when printing the file to pdf. 
When copy pasting the text exported on the PDF, we have a complete different text than the original.

Comment: So, to be sure I understand, printing to pdf creates a pdf document with the correct characters, but if you then attempt to copy and paste from the pdf document the pasted text has the incorrect characters? If that's the case then this is definitely not a LibreOffice issue. Have you installed Farsi/Arabic language support [at the OS level](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/prefs-language-install.html.en)?

Comment: You understood my problem! I installed the Arabic language, but the problem is still here... Actually, copy/pasting the PDF content generates a pattern of words. I will update my questions detailling this pattern.